# Storing date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, store

I want the date to be added to an orders table I have created, once the user proceeds to checkout. The code I currently has just prints:

> "Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Here's my code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, total, order_date) VALUES ('$name', '$total', 'DATETIME: Auto NOW()', NOW() )";
```

The name and total columns store but the date does not. How can I solve this?

Comment: Give us ur table layout

Comment: Why not use PHP's `date()` function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: You have 3 values INTO and 4 values in the VALUES ... case solved

Comment: You have three fields in your column list, and four values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, total, order_date) VALUES ('$name', '$total', NOW())";
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert data inside  customer_id, total, order_date (3 rows) but you are sendig '$name', '$total', 'DATETIME: Auto NOW()', NOW(), FOUR.

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that you that the number of fields does not match the number of values. That seems correct: your query tries to insert 4 values into 3 fields. You'd probably have to rewrite the query to

`$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, total, order_date) VALUES ('$name', '$total', NOW() )";`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need 3 values: customer_id, total, order_date

but you give 4 :'$name', '$total', 'DATETIME: Auto NOW()', NOW()

Maybe it should look like this:

```
"INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, total, order_date) VALUES ('$name', '$total', NOW() )";
```